# Preseed install from local repository

Tags: apt, system-installation, repository, preseed

I'm having a little difficulty in doing a preseed install from a local repository. I've pointed everything at my local apt-mirror. However, if I change d-i apt-setup/security_host string

to point at my repository, instead of security.ubuntu.com, I get a "can't find kernel modules" error message on start. Is there a separate step for mirroring security?

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian, and the security mirror is something that you should not replace with anything else. Please read this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5009/351996

Comment: Unless you want 100% identical installs 100% of the time. If security repo puts in a newer package than what other machines have, I have to possibly run a full QA regression on our entire sw stack to make sure no behaviour was changed. When we do update our mirrors, we phase it in after an extensive testing period. If you really can't change this to something under your own control, then ubuntu/debian isn't usable as a production OS.